# How to output numbers without type tag with circe-yaml?

Tags: scala, yaml, circe

Following code using circe-yaml produces the output below. While the output is correct, it is not very nice. In my case the output is expected to be read and further edited by humans, therefore I would like to have it as natural as possible.

How can I configure [Circe-YAML](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml) (or [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src) which is used by it) so that it outputs numbers without the `!!int tag`? Both `1000` and `1000.0` are acceptable representations for me, `!!int '1000.0'` is not.

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

object Main extends App {
  case class Data(x: Double, y: Double)

  val foo = Seq(
    Data(0.0000001, 100000000),
    Data(0.1234567891234569, 1000)
  )

  val json = foo.asJson

  val printer = yaml.Printer.spaces2
  val yamlString = printer.pretty(json)

  println(yamlString)
}
```

```
- x: 1.0E-7
  y: !!int '1.0E8'
- x: 0.1234567891234569
  y: !!int '1000.0'
```

Note: I wrote this in the [Circe-yaml issue #68](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml/issues/68) as well.

Comment: YAML 1.1 has been outdated for close to 10 (ten!) years now, maybe you should try another library like [snakeyaml-engine](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml-engine/src/default/) that supports YAML 1.2

Comment: Well, I do not use SnakeYAML directly, I use Circe-YAML, which seems to be using it. I am certainly willing to  check how difficult would it be to modify the library to use snakeyaml-engine instead. That said, could you elaborate on how will using YAML 1.2 instead of YAML 1.1 solve the problem?

Comment: I am not 100% sure whether that will solve it, but I assumed that snakeyaml has restrictions on the size of integers that it supports, that is why 100000000 is essentially represented as a string representation of float in YAML and then cast to an int with the tag. It being YAML 1.1 I assumed it is likely to be updated/maintained. If you try snakeyaml-engine, make sure to test it directly with a small example before trying to integrate it in Circle-YAML.

Comment: "snakeyaml has restrictions on the size of integers that it supports" This sounded probable, but a brief source inspection does not support this, values are always stored as strings: [line 29 of ScalarNode.java](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/601ef081c90e0e12c7de0d73eb8a47e1e05c867e/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/nodes/ScalarNode.java#lines-29)

Comment: You are right that is nonsense, if size (32bit) were the reason than `1000` would have a "normal" (i.e. non-tagged) representation.